# Track when a user ignored duplicate management warning and creates record?

Tags: apex, duplicate-management

I have the following requirement:

When a user clicks "create and ignore warning" when creating a record and thereby overrules the duplicate management, I need to have a list of these records which were created even though there was a warning.

Is there some way to do this?

If I knew how to check that there was a warning and he ignored it, I would then set a checkbox "CreatedByIgnoringWarning" or something to true and then I have my list already. But I don't know how I would go about the check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the option 'Report' when configuring your duplicate rule. Create a custom report type to show duplicate records.

Check this link for more information:
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=duplicate_management_custom_report_types.htm&language=en_US

In apex, you can catch duplicate records while inserting if the DML throws Database.DuplicateError, you can then set your checkbox 'CreatedByIgnoringWarning' on the record and update it.

Comment: Awesome! Thank your very much.